# Why use NSRange on strings when there appears to be a perfectly good substring method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning native iOS development for the first time, and I came across the struct NSRange. I come from a Java background so I don't really see the reasoning for using a range struct when you can just use substring methods that are part of the `NSString` class. What is the advantage of using range structs over using the non-range `NSString` substring methods.

Thanks!

edit:
Looks like I was considering the substring methods: `substringFromIndex:` and `substringToIndex:`.
Considering the inflexibility of these methods (ie. not being able to choose both a start AND end point) makes the range struct instances more necessary. Though I guess you could also nest those two methods to achieve the same result.

edit 2: Examples.

Non-range substring method examples:

```
NSString *str = @"This is a string.";

NSString *substr = [str substringToIndex:7];

NSString *substr2 = [str substringFromIndex:7];
```

Ranges substring method example:

```
NSString *substr3 = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 5)];
```

Comment: NSRange is a general purpose class which can be used for many things, not just string sub ranges. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "just substring methods"? There *are* substring methods on `NSString`.

Comment: @Inafziger Except that `NSRange` isn't a class.

Comment: @Inafziger: Right it's a struct. Like I said I'm a java programmer. (We don't have structs ;) ).

Comment: @H2CO3 My question is why use range objects... or structs or whatever instead of using the substring methods that come with NSString.

Comment: The general-purpose substring method (`substringWithRange:`) takes an `NSRange`. What do you mean "instead of using the substring methods?" Could you provide a couple of code examples of what you think these two mechanisms are?

Comment: -1 for making us guess what you're talking about. There are lots of substring methods in NSString: some use ranges, some use indices, some use substrings.

Comment: Haha, true about it being a struct.  I guess that I should have said that it is a general purpose collection of functions which act upon a struct, and can be used to describe a range for many purposes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the range based methods offer a lot more flexibility, and they are also easily usable with all of the `NSString` search methods (which use ranges heavily). In general, if you're going to create a substring you need to know where to start or end and that information is likely to have come from a search, thus you have a range.